# Bibliography doesn't show up on Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, overleaf

I created a .tex file like below:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\begin{document} 
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

An entry in the `references.bib` looks like this:

```
@article{belter2013mechanical,
  title={Mechanical design and performance specifications of anthropomorphic prosthetic hands: A review.},
  author={Belter, Joseph T and Segil, Jacob L and Dollar, Aaron M and Weir, Richard F},
  journal={Journal of Rehabilitation Research \& Development},
  volume={50},
  number={5},
  year={2013}
}
```

The bibliography is not appearing on Overleaf, shows only '?' marks. I'm getting Package natbib Warning:Citation,

> You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography.
> Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in
> your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.

The same code works perfectly with Texmaker on local machine

Comment: Your example is incomplete, did you actually cite something? Is `spbasoc` compatible with `natbib` do you get any compilation errors in Overleaf?

Comment: I changed the line \bibliography{references} to \bibliography{references.bib} and it worked.

Comment: unless you have `references.bib.bib` then that is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to upload files from Springer at https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates to overleaf.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}   
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\begin{document} 
The issue cannot be reproduce with~\cite{belter2013mechanical}.
\bibliography{references} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I changed the line \bibliography{references}  to \bibliography{references.bib} and it worked.